# Storing KnockoutJS modeled data with AmplifyJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, amplifyjs

I'm trying to figure out a way to cache my knockoutJS SPA data and I've been experimenting with amplifyJS. Here's one of my GET functions:

```js
UserController.prototype.getUsers = function() {
   var self = this;

   return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: self.Config.api + 'users'
   }).done(function(data) {
      self.usersArr(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.users, function(item) {
         // run each item through model
         return new self.Model.User(item);
      }));         
   }).fail(function(data) {
      // failed
   });
};
```

Here's the same function, "amplified":

```js
UserController.prototype.getUsers = function() {
   var self = this;

   if (amplify.store('users')) {
      self.usersArr(ko.utils.arrayMap(amplify.store('users'), function(item) {
         // run each item through model
         return new self.Model.User(item);
      }));
  } else {
     return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: self.Config.api + 'users'
     }).done(function(data) {
        self.usersArr(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.users, function(item) {
           // run each item through model
           return new self.Model.User(item);
        }));         
     }).fail(function(data) {
      // failed
   });
};
```

This works as expected, but I'm not sure about the approach I used, because it will also require extra work on the `addUser`, `removeUser` and `editUser` functions. And seeing as I have many more similar functions throughout my app, I'd like to avoid the extra code if possible.

I've found a way of handling things with the help of `ko.extenders`, like so:

```js
this.usersArr = ko.observableArray().extend({ localStore: 'users'  });
```

Then use the `ko.extenders.localStore` function to update the local storage data whenever it detects a change inside the `observableArray`. So on init it will write to the `observableArray` in case local storage data exists for `users` key and on changes it will update the local storage data.

My problem with this approach is that I need to run my data through the model and I couldn't find a way to do that from the `localStore` function, which is kept on a separate page.

Has any of you worked with KO and Amplify? What approach did you use? Should I use the first one or try a combination of the two and rewrite the extender in a way that it only updates the local storage without writing to the `observableArray` on init?

Comment: So... you want a persistent cache layer that not only holds server data but reflects user changes, too?

Comment: Yes, user changes need to be reflected as well in cases where the page is refreshed or the same info is requested on another view after the original object has been altered.

Comment: You do not intend to build something that can be used completely offline, correct?

Comment: Correct. I want to cache the data just to improve page loads and reduce server requests.

Comment: Would an intelligent caching policy (conditional GET with `Last-Modified` and `If-Modified-Since` headers, etc, for  your Ajax requests) not serve the same purpose without the added complexity of yet another library?

Comment: I'm ... not familiar with this method. How does it work, exactly? Do I send out a `If-Modified-Since` header on each GET and if the API returns 304, it means that I can use my cached version of the previous GET? But where is that cache stored?

Comment: In the regular browser cache. Ajax responses are cacheable just like anything else, it entirely depends on the headers you send along with them. If you send `Last-Modified` the browser will send `If-Modified-Since` on its own. You just need to adapt the server side. If your server responds 304 fast, requests can be very quick. 304 responses are completely transparent in jQuery. If you send `Cache-Control:` with `max-age`, then the browser might not even issue a new physical request at all if the cached response is still considered fresh. Check `E-Tag`/`If-None-Match`/`If-Match`, too.

Comment: I'll have a talk with the API guys and will definitely try this out. You can submit this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Implementing a working conditional request mechanism can be a bit tricky, but it's definitely worth it. It takes some reading into the different caching headers and some experimenting, but in the end you will reduce load on the server tier (DB, too!) without increasing complexity on the client, since all of this is built into HTTP anyway. If you use knockout's mapping plugin with a `key` function (see ["Advanced Usage"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#advanced-usage)) you can save additional time on the client.

Comment: If at some point you have feedback, I'd be happy to hear how it went.

Comment: Had the talk and we're doing it this way, but we have other stuff on our plates, so it might take a while. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, then good luck! I hope it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the question's comments, I suggested to use native HTTP caching instead of adding *another* caching layer on the client by means of an extra library.

This would require implementing a conditional request scheme.

Such a scheme relies on freshness information in the Ajax response headers via the `Last-Modified` (or `E-Tag`) HTTP headers and other headers that influence browser caching (like `Cache-Control:` with its various options).

- The browser transparently sends an `If-Modified-Since` (or `If-None-Match`) header to the server when the same resource (URL) is requested subsequently.
- The server can respond with HTTP `304 Not Modified` if the client's information is still up-to-date. This can be a lot faster than re-creating a full response from scratch.
- From the Ajax request's point of view (jQuery or otherwise) a response works the same way, no matter if it actually came from the server or if it came from the browser's cache, the latter is only a lot faster.

Carefully adapting the server side is necessary for this, the client side on the other hand does not need much change.

The benefit of implementing conditional requests is reduced load on the server and faster response behavior on the client.

A specialty of Knockout to improve this even further:

If you happen to use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to map raw server data to a complex view model, you can define - as part of the options that control the mapping process - a `key` function. Its purpose is to match parts of your view model against parts of the source data.

This way parts of the data that already have been mapped will not be mapped again, the others are updated. That can help reduce the client's processing time for data it already has and, potentially, unnecessary screen updates as well.